# Tried to change value on "onchange" event, it only updates first not second

Tags: javascript, php

When I tried to change value on onchange function it only updates first one not second. I want to change value Manually. in this problem you see 2 and 2 is equal to 4 but when I want to change second row like there show 4 multiple 4 is equal 16. when change 4 as 5 then its conflict first row I want changes in same row . please help to sort out this problem.

`test.php`

```
<html>
<title>
Test
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function taxapply(){
var one=document.getElementById('one').value;
//alert(one);
var two=document.getElementById('two').value;
//alert(two);
var equal=one*two;
document.getElementById('equal').innerHTML=equal.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('equals').value=equal.toFixed(2);
alert(equal);
}

</script>
<body>
<?php
require_once('DB.class.php'); 
$db = new DB();
$db->connect();
$result=$db->SelectTable("multiple","","");
?>
<table class=" table table-bordered table-hover" border="1" align="center" width="50%">
<tr>
<th><strong>Sr.No.</strong></th>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>Equal</th>                              
</tr>       
<?php
if(count($result) > 0)
{
foreach($result as $rslist12){
?>
<tr>
<?php $i =$i+1;
?>
<td align="center" ><?php echo $i;?></td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="one" id="one"  style="width:60px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['one'];?>" onchange="taxapply()";></td>
<td align="center" ><input type="text" name="two" id="two"  style="width:60px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['two'];?>" onchange="taxapply()";></td>
<td align="center" ><label id="equal"><input type="text" name="equal" id="equal" style="width:50px;"   value="<?php echo $rslist12['equal'];?>" onchange="taxapply()";></label></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>  
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

DB.class.php

```
<?php
class DB {
protected $db_name = 'plus2net';
protected $db_user = 'root';
protected $db_pass = '';
protected $db_host = 'localhost'; 
function __construct() {  
$connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

return true;
}  
public function connect(){
$connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
mysql_select_db($this->db_name);

return true;
}
public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow=false)
{
$resultArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowSet))
{
array_push($resultArray, $row);
}

if($singleRow === true)
return $resultArray[0];

return $resultArray;
}
public function SelectTable($table, $where="",$fieldarray="",$debug="") {
if ($fieldarray=="")
{
$f_list = "*";
}
else
{ 
$f_list = $fieldarray ;
}
$sql = "SELECT $f_list FROM $table ";
if(  ! empty( $where ) )
$sql .= " WHERE  $where";

if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if( ! $result )
return 0;
return $this->processRowSet($result);
}
public function SelectSingle($table, $where,$fieldarray="",$debug="") {
if ($fieldarray=="")
{
$f_list = "*";
}
else
{ 
$f_list = $fieldarray ;
}
$sql = "SELECT $f_list FROM $table ";
if(  ! empty( $where ) )
$sql .= " WHERE  $where";

if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if( ! $result )
return 0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
return $this->processRowSet($result, true);
}
public function Update($table,$where,$data,$debug="") {

foreach ( $data as $column=>$value )
{
if($value !="now()"){
$fv[] = "$column = \""."$value"."\"";
}else{
$fv[]= "$column = "."$value"."";
}
}
$fv_list = trim(implode(", ", $fv));

$sql = "UPDATE $table SET "."$fv_list"." WHERE $where";
if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
return true;
}
public function Insert($table,$data,$debug="") {

$columns = "";
$values = "";
foreach( $data as $column=>$value )
{
$field[] = $column;
if($value !="now()")
$values[] = "'$value'";
else
$values[] = "$value";
}
$columns = trim( implode(", ", $field) );
$values = trim( implode(", ", $values) );

$sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";
if($debug==1){echo $sql;exit();}
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//return the ID of the user in the database.
return mysql_insert_id();

}
public function Delete($table, $condition)
{

$query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $condition";
$result = mysql_query( $query);
if( ! $result )
return 0;
return 1;
}

}
?>
```

Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `multiple` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`one` int(11) NOT NULL,
`two` int(11) NOT NULL,
`equal` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `multiple` (`id`, `one`, `two`, `equal`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 4),
(2, 4, 4, 16);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <html>
    <title>
    Test
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function taxapply(obj){
        var id = obj.id;
        var idNo = id.substr(id.indexOf('-')+1);
    var one=document.getElementById('one-'+idNo).value;
    var two=document.getElementById('two-'+idNo).value;
    var equal=one*two;
    document.getElementById('equal-'+idNo).innerHTML=equal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('equals-'+idNo).value=equal.toFixed(2);
    }

    </script>
    <body>
    <?php
    require_once('DB.class.php'); 
    $db = new DB();
    $db->connect();
    $result=$db->SelectTable("multiple","","");
    ?>
    <table class=" table table-bordered table-hover" border="1" align="center" width="50%">
    <tr>
    <th><strong>Sr.No.</strong></th>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
    <th>Equal</th>                              
    </tr>       
    <?php
    if(count($result) > 0)
    {
    $i=0;
    foreach($result as $rslist12){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <?php 
    $i =$i+1;
    ?>
    <td align="center" ><?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="one" id="one-<?php echo $i; ?>"  style="width:60px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['one'];?>" onchange="taxapply(this)";></td>
    <td align="center" ><input type="text" name="two" id="two-<?php echo $i; ?>"  style="width:60px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['two'];?>" onchange="taxapply(this)";></td>
    <td align="center" ><label id="equal-<?php echo $i; ?>"><input type="text" name="equal" id="equals-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width:50px;"   value="<?php echo $rslist12['equal'];?>" onchange="taxapply(this)";></label></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>  
    </table>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple ids of same value and in this case browser picks up the first element having that id

in your problem elements with id'one' and 'two' are present multiple times

`document.getElementById('one').value` will always get you first element with 'one' id

so either make the ids dynamic or give reference to those elements using `this` parameter passing the object to `taxapply` function

Comment: and you have `$i` variable which is not initiated properly

Comment: you have 2 elements with same id value in your webpage

Answer (score 0):

You could use bellow code for dynamic id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function taxapply(i){
    var one=document.getElementById('one'+i).value;
    //alert(one);
    var two=document.getElementById('two'+i).value;
    //alert(two);
    var equal=one*two;
    document.getElementById('equal'+i).innerHTML=equal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('equals').value=equal.toFixed(2);
    alert(equal);
}
</javascript>
```

Here is your HTML code

```
<td align="center" ><?php echo $i;?></td>
<td align="center">
    <input type="text" name="one" id="one<?php echo $i;?>" style="width:60px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['one'];?>" onchange="taxapply(<?php echo $i;?>)";>
</td>
<td align="center" >
    <input type="text" name="two<?php echo $i;?>" id="two"  style="width:60px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['two'];?>" onchange="taxapply(<?php echo $i;?>)";>
</td>
<td align="center" >
    <input type="text" name="equal" id="equal<?php echo $i;?>" style="width:50px;" value="<?php echo $rslist12['equal'];?>" onchange="taxapply(<?php echo $i;?>)";>
</td>
</tr>
```

This type of code sample working for me.

Comment: Could you use `onchange="taxapply('<?php echo $i;?>')"`